# access to AppData/Roaming is denied

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, sqlite

Visual Studio 2010 makes the solution in two Configurations: x86 & x64. In x86 configuration, I've no problem. In x64 configuration I get the following error:

> SQLitePureImageCache, moving data: System.IO.IOException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\app\' is denied.
>      at System.IO.Directory.InternalMove(String sourceDirName, String destDirName, Boolean checkHost)
>      at GMap.NET.Internals.Cache..ctor() in D:\mnt\11\home\hamidi\behnama\client\GMap\GMap.NET\GMap.NET.Core\GMap.NET.Internals\Cache.cs:line 101
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in GMap.NET.Core.dll

which user is my login user and app is my application name. I think it's not relevant to SQLite itself or its assemblies. Something seems to be wrong with the app in 64-bit mode.

Comment: I wrote a simple code to access a file in the Roaming folder. It throws an access denied exception ONLY is 64-bit output application! So, we may be sure that the problem is not an SQLite issue.

Comment: i tried the code in a separate project and it works well!

Comment: I correct it: access to the file Log.txt is denied. but i may access the file Data.gmdb without any problem. i may even read from it in multiple threads at the same time. the file is what map tiles are cached into.